# How to open drawer with iconbutton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Well, I was trying to create my custom appbar but I keep editing my column widget with properties I wanted in my appbar and it worked same as I wanted the appbar(as you can see in image) so I thought I dont need a appbar now. But now I want to implement a drawer which can be access by my iconbutton (which is implemented in top left corner of my widget). Actually drawer is implemented bcoz i can use it with sliding action, but I think its hidden behind my widget! I searched on internet and found some codes but since I dont have deep knowledge of any other programming knowledge so its little hard to understand the syntax for me. How can I access this drawer with my IconButton???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI8vo.png)

This is my page source code. NOTE: sorry i could not update the upper part of my bcoz i dont know how to format it in stackoverflow so its getting input as text instead of code snippet so I am avoiding it

```
  return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  drawer: CstmDrawer(),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 150.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 130.0,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                        bottom: Radius.elliptical(
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 100.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); //I found this code on internet but it gives error "Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold."
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.notifications_active_outlined)),
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 20.0,
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.black),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            hintText: "Search Here",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Drawer source code.

```
return Drawer(
            elevation: 16.0,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  onDetailsPressed: (){},
                  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      tooltip: "Add Photo",
                      splashColor: Colors.black,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.add_a_photo_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  accountName: Text(
                    "My Name"
                  ),
                  accountEmail: Text(
                    "myemail@gmail.com",
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  //tileColor: Colors.green,
                  onTap: (){},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                  hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                  title: Text("My Account"),
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: (){},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
                  hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                  title: Text("Cart"),
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: (){},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.storefront_sharp),
                  hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                  title: Text("Shop"),
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: (){},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                  hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                  title: Text("Map"),
                ),
                Divider(
                  thickness: 2.0,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: (){},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                  title: Text("Settings"),
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: (){},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
                  hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                  title: Text("Logout"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
  );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your context does not contains yet the data from your `Scaffold`, the workaround you can apply would be to use a `GlobalKey` to refer to your current `ScaffoldState`:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: CstmDrawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 150.0,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 130.0,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                            bottom: Radius.elliptical(
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 100.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            /// Use the _scaffoldKey to call openDrawer()
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
                              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.notifications_active_outlined)),
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined)),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 20.0,
                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40.0,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                          child: Theme(
                            data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.black),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                hintText: "Search Here",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the solution is to use `_scaffoldKey` to call `openDrawer()` so instead of doing `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()` you will do `_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()`, and do not forget to assign the key to your `Scaffold`, by doing `key: _scaffoldKey`.

Comment: This worked very well!!! Thanks a lot brother. I was alredy using a globalkey for scaffold and also implemented properly but my syntax was wrong on onpressed event... I was using "Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();" which was not working. And your code "_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()," worked!!!! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use this I guess!

```html
IconButton(
         icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
         onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()
     )
```

Comment: I did this bro you can see in my code... I also added comment that its not working..This code also required a globalkey which I am using too. But its not working as well

Comment: I think it's just `.openDrawer` (without`()`). It worked for me this way for me at least